# How can I make mobile bar not block the bottom of my page?

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

I have tried everything. The body should not scroll as I run into issues with overscrolling on Safari iOS and Safari webapps (save to homescreen), so instead the main div "`#content`", has all the content with overflow scrolling.

**The problem** is, when `#content` is set to `100vh`, the mobile bar, covers the bottom of the content. This is a common occurrence according to Google, and I've seen many solutions but the main one that worked is setting `height: -webkit-fill-available;`, but unfortunately this stops `#content` from scrolling on Chrome Windows.

**main.css** (with scrolling not working on Chrome Windows)

```css
body, html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    position: fixed;   
}

#content {
    /* height: 100vh;    Scrollbar present (good) on Safari iOS, Chrome iOS, Chrome Windows, but 
                         bottom of page blocked by browser menu bar on Safari iOS and Chrome iOS (bad) */
    height: -webkit-fill-available;  /* Scrollbar present on Safari iOS, Chrome iOS (good), scrollbar 
                                        present but no actual bar to scroll down present
                                        on Chrome Windows, can't scroll down (very bad), bottom of page 
                                        not blocked by browser menu bar on Safari iOS, Chrome iOS (good) */
    width: 100vw;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-gb">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>React App</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="root">
            <div id="content">
                <b>START<br/>3<br/>2<br/>1<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>END<br/></b>  
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            // Stops overscrolling on "saved to home page" webapps
            window.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Probably goes without saying but, this isn't the actual page, it's how it would be constructed with React.

Sorry if I haven't provided enough detail, please say if you need any information—I'll provide it; I'm at my wits' end, I am 15 years old and I've been trying to make this page how I want it for days now.

**Images and videos to show**

1. [Chrome Windows, `height: 100vh;`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uNN7.gif) (wanted behaviour, can scroll)
2. [Chrome Windows, `height: -webkit-fill-available;`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuT7b.png) (unwanted behaviour, can't scroll)
3. [Safari iOS, `height: 100vh;`](https://i.imgur.com/3RmasIA.mp4) (unwanted behaviour, bottom of page blocked by Safari menu bar)
4. [Safari iOS, `height: -webkit-fill-available;`](https://i.imgur.com/iZQAmJs.mp4) (wanted behaviour, bottom of page not blocked by Safari menu bar)

1 and 4 are what I want to achieve.

Thank you so so so much if you can help me :)

Comment: Does setting min-height to -webkit-fill-available (in several places) help? See most recent (jan 2021) update in comments from Guillaume Grassiant at [link]https://allthingssmitty.com/2020/05/11/css-fix-for-100vh-in-mobile-webkit/#:~:text=The%20idea%20behind%20-webkit-fill-available%20%E2%80%93%20at%20least%20at,like%20this%20aren%E2%80%99t%20fully%20supported%20by%20the%20CSSWG. though other commentators talks of resorting to JS.

Comment: It didn't seem to do much; I have created a solution through Javascript which I'll post below. I saw that article before, crazy how big an issue this is.

Answer (score 4):

This works but it uses Javascript, not too heartbreaking as I already had to use it to stop the overscroll. Kind of annoying how much Javascript you have to use to combat Safari!

```js
const resizer = () => {
    document.getElementById("content").style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
}

window.addEventListener("resize", (_e) => resizer());

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (_e) => resizer());
```

Comment: This worked for me. `.style.height = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight || 0, window.innerHeight || 0) + "px"` Thanks for the code

Answer (score 0):

You say you tried everything so this a bit silly of me to ask but have you tried `@media`?

```
#content {height: 100vh; ...}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #content {height: -webkit-fill-available;}
}
```

If you tried this, what the result?

Comment: I had tried this but was uncomfortable with relying on screensizes. It's annoying because the behaviour of Safari and Chrome do not match